# sharepoint list 2010 - forms

Tags: list, form

First I have built a helpdesk system using a SharePoint 2010 list with 10 workflows and it's up and running since 2 years with custom asp page show online statistic.

Now I have an issue to build toner inventory system linked with helpdesk

The process should be as the following, and I only need help with step one:

1. In the same opening new ticket form refer to the helpdesk list, when the user choose ticket type = toner from the list of ticket type; new 2 filed should appear asking to choose the printer type from the list and cartridge number from the list, where the printer + cartridge lists are populated from toner inventory list
2. For each cartridge should be a ticket where every cartridge should be requested separately, not as group
3. Any ticket request must deduct from the available balance in the toner inventory list
4. IT user can add new toner and it should collect and sum over the available balance in the toner inventory list
5. Each transaction need notification
6. …
7. …
8. …

etc.

I only need help with the first step. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you look into Cascading Dropdowns, provided by SPServices/jQuery. This will allow your users to have a selection, which then drives the subsequent choices. It uses mulitlple lists as the source data in a quasi relational manner.

So in efect, you do this work on the client side and then post a normal List update to your helpdesk application.

[SP Services](http://spservices.codeplex.com/)